# iTunes suddenly decided my mp3s are mpga movies that iTunes won't play. What happened?

Tags: itunes, error

I have a bunch of music I ripped from CD myself. I haven't played all of it recently, mostly listening to my iPhone instead. I went to play some old tracks only to be told by iTunes "this movie requires QuickTime, which is not supported by this version of iTunes".

1. It's not a movie.
2. It's not like I changed anything. (Might have upgraded iTunes.)
3. Other tracks off the same CD are still playable.
4. Why doesn't iTunes support QuickTime?

Have you run into this? How would I get around it, short of re-ripping all those CDs? And is there a way to determine which tracks have been affected short of trying to play every one of my thousands of songs?

Comment: Mac or PC? Version of iTunes and OS?

Comment: This was a year and more ago. It was an up to date Apple at that time, but the problem's since resolved itself.

Comment: The site bumps questions without a resolved check mark periodically hence the attention. Feel free to accept your answer or edit it if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround, which also makes no sense: as explained at [this link](http://appletoolbox.com/2012/07/itunes-for-mac-this-movie-requires-quicktime-which-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-itunes-error-fix/), switch iTunes to run in 32 bit mode via the Info box.

This doesn't explain parts 1-4, but it does at least make the tracks playable. I'd still love to know what is actually going on.

Also, you can enable the "Kind" column and sort by it to discover which of your tracks have mysteriously been converted to Quicktime Movies.

Comment: Switching iTunes to 32 bits makes it use the 32 bits version of QuickTime which is far more powerful than the 64 bits version (for instance pulgins only work with the 32 bits QuickTime). Hope that helps.